# How i can check if session is still valid or not in whatsapp-web.js

Tags: node.js, api, whatsapp

I want to check my login session is valid or not , for example if any user logout from device, how i can validate the session and return user to qr-code page.

```
const client = new Client({
  restartOnAuthFail: true,
  puppeteer: {
    handleSIGINT: false,
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],

  },
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
    clientId: "client-one",
  })

})

client.initialize();
```

here is my client.
which method i call to check.
Please help me
Thansks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this Client events: `authenticated`, `ready` or `disconnected`